# python multiprocessing Pool with multiple arguments and recursion

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm currently trying to use pool multiprocessing function in order to calculate multiple part of tables at the same time. My code is basically:

```
def funtion(tab1,tab2,...)
  ...

def function_wrapper(args):
  return function(*args)

pool = Pool(processes=num_thread)
arg = [(table1(i,:),table2(i,:),...)for i in range(1000)]
pool.map(function_wrapper, arg)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

And I get the error: IndexError: too many indices .

Is someone can help me to write correctly this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table1(i,:)` should have raised a SyntaxError. `funtion` should probably be `function`.
Please modify the code below so that we have runnable code which exhibits the IndexError. Otherwise, as you can see below, there is no error in the code you posted.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def function(tab1,tab2):
    return tab1+tab2

def function_wrapper(args):
    return function(*args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool()
    arg = [(i,i) for i in range(1000)]
    print(pool.map(function_wrapper, arg))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: In deed the error wasn't here but python showed me this line, that's why I thougth the error was here. Thank you! (And maybe this piece of code will help other multiprocessing beginers^^)